# Azure B2C Authentication within BlazorWebView

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, maui, azure-ad-b2c

In a Maui-blazor application, I need to Sign In only with Azure B2C without opening a pop-up login.

I'm trying to use the [Handle authentication within the `BlazorWebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=maui#handle-authentication-within-the-blazorwebview-option-2) but I have no idea of what to do in this method because usually in a classic Blazor wasm flow, there is nothing special to do excepting specify the `LoginMode` to `"redirect"`:

```
private Task<ClaimsPrincipal> LoginWithExternalProviderAsync()
{
    /*
        Provide OpenID/MSAL code to authenticate the user. See your identity 
        provider's documentation for details.
        Return a new ClaimsPrincipal based on a new ClaimsIdentity.
    */
    var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
    return Task.FromResult(authenticatedUser);
}
```

**Edit**:
I gone through this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) and take a look to the Blazor WebAssembly [Sign in users (B2C)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/blob/main/WebApp-OIDC/B2C/README.md) but without success. On the application, it opens a blank page in a browser, but it is working on a classic Blazor webassembly project.

Comment: According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow), Azure B2C can get the login token without the login page. So you can call the api with a custom login page.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT When I try to do something by this way, I get this answer `The orchestration step '1' does not specify a CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId when one was expected`

Comment: You can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes) about the answer and [how to deal with it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys).